# How can we identify the relationship between two SQL Server tables , either one to one or some other relationship.....?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we identify the relationship between two SQL Server tables, either one to one or some other relationship.....?

Comment: look at foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, create a new view in your database, add the two tables you want to see the relationship with.

[image]

Comment: The designer is evil

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check what all tables are connected to the table, Just right click on table and go to View dependencies

[image: View dependencies of a table]
and find out. And you can check all constrains by checking create  query for that table.

[image: check all table label constraints in its query]

i think it will help you out . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft system views for that purpose:

```
SELECT  
    obj.name AS fk
    ,sch.name AS [schema_name]
    ,tabParent.name AS [table]
    ,colParent.name AS [column]
    ,tabRef.name AS [referenced_table]
    ,colRef.name AS [referenced_column]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
JOIN sys.objects obj ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
JOIN sys.tables tabParent ON tabParent.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tabParent.schema_id = sch.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns colParent ON colParent.column_id = parent_column_id AND colParent.object_id = tabParent.object_id
JOIN sys.tables tabRef ON tabRef.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
JOIN sys.columns colRef ON colRef.column_id = referenced_column_id AND colRef.object_id = tabRef.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas schRef ON tabRef.schema_id = schRef.schema_id
WHERE schRef.name = N'dbo'
AND tabRef.name = N'Projects'
```

It is possible to filter this query by referenced tables or columns, or just to look for everything that references a specific column.